# redux-form: path.lastIndexOf is not a function error thrown while unmounting component due to "Object object" as form name

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

While using `connect` from Redux & `reduxForm` Redux-form upon page transition my frontend throws error:

> path.lastIndexOf is not a function

and it most likely caused by this name issue (Object object):

[image]

This is the code that wraps my form component with HOCs:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(reduxForm({ form: 'sigin', validate })(LoginForm))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some debugging I found the issue, I just had to replace the order.

```
reduxForm({ form: 'sigin', validate})(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginForm))
```

I just found it frustrating that Google doesn't show anything related to either error message or `object Object` attribute name in Redux. So if someone else comes to similar errors, just replace the order of HOCs.

Comment: I have a same issue although the above did not solve it. Did you adjust anything else? My form exists within a JSX if statement and when the API returns a successful response, an action is dispatch which in-turn hides the form and shows a thank you message.

Comment: this then leads to `TypeError: path.lastIndexOf is not a function` on redux-form v4.2.0